# .NET 4.5 Dynamic Display and Error Attribute

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, razor-2

I have a typical sign-up form with two radio buttons (Personal or Corporate).

I am using the regular `LabelFor` and `ValidationMessageFor` for **Name**, that can be **Personal Name** or **Corporate Name**.

When we have scenarios that according to the Radio Button choice (Client Side) the requested data will change (Labels and Required Messages) what's the correct approach ?

I am aware that I can change the values through Jquery, but I want to keep those messages as resources for future Multi language implementation. Or should I add both to the Form and make them visible and invisible according to user selection?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using a framework like [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/).  There is a great implementation of it for MVC [here](http://knockoutmvc.com/).

Personally, I've gone the whole route of trying to keep as many things server side as possible, but since embracing knockoutJS, my life with things like this on the client side is much simpler :)

Comment: So what about the ViewModel attributes? The display and error? With Knockout JS I will still be using those HTML Helpers? Thanks